# Issue comparing dates from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to create a script in Python that works with a CSV and grabs the information based on the conditional. I am having an issue with comparing dates. The dates from the CSV of course come as strings and are in the format "6/23/2020" but when I try to compare to datetime.now with appending a time to the dates from the CSV it gives an output that is obviously incorrect.

I'm sure there is a better way to get these dates to be comparable and that might be causing the issue but I'm not sure how it is coming to this output.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import argparse


col_list = ["LN", "FN", "DB", "F_DOD", "SRC", "Q_FACTOR"]
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\file.csv", usecols=col_list)

def diff_dates(date1, date2):
    d1 = dt.strptime(date1, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    d2 = dt.strptime(date2, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)


now = dt.now()

for row in range(len(df)):
    fn = df.loc[row, "FN"]
    ln = df.loc[row, "LN"]
    dob = df.loc[row, "DB"]
    qf = df.loc[row, "Q_FACTOR"]
    dod = df.loc[row, "F_DOD"]
    time = "00:00:00"
    #now_converted = dt.strftime(now, "%m/%d/%Y")
    dod_appended = f'{dod} {time}'
    dod_convert = dt.strptime(dod_appended, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    dod_converted = dt.strftime(dod_convert, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    now_converted = dt.strftime(now, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    if qf == 100 & diff_dates(now_converted, dod_converted) <= 365:
        print(fn, ln, dod, qf)
```

Note:

I've ran a manual check on the CSV and the output should contain almost 180 rows

output:

```
fname lname 9/30/1976 100
fname lname 2/4/1991 100
fname lname 11/22/1952 100
fname lname 3/14/2020 100
```

First 5 Rows of Data:

```
F_DOD           F_LN    F_FN        Q_FACTOR
11/23/1954      LName   FName       100
4/23/1964       LName   FName       100
9/30/1976       LName   FName       50
4/18/2018       LName   FName       100 
6/4/2004        LName   FName       100
```

Comment: It seems like you're doing lots of extra work repeatedly formatting and parsing dates. Try just parsing the date when you read from the CSV, do all the calculations with dates, and finally format when printing.

Comment: And if the date doesn't include a time, why are you appending the time to it?

Comment: @Barmar This is just a temporary fix to get past the errors. I understand its not the best code or concise at all. I'm more concerned with the output not matching what the conditional states.

Comment: why not convert the date first ? `pd.to_datetime(...,format='%m/%d/%Y')` can you provide a snippet of your data? the top 5 rows will do

Comment: @Datanovice That will probably work best, I'll definitely change it to that. I have edited the post and added some sample data, although I had to remove the names.

Comment: I suggest you add some print statements so you can see the intermediate values. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the logic.